# How is the bin package of confluent platform / kafka built?

Tags: confluent-platform

I see that the tarball present in http://packages.confluent.io/archive/5.1/confluent-5.1.0-2.11.tar.gz

contains dependency jars arranged in different folder structure ,with dependent jar files distributed according to categories in **share/java/** folder

However , when i clone the git of confluent kafka v_5.1 and build the project , all the dependent jar files are present in **lib/** folder instead .

Is this because of a different gradle definition ? where can i obtain the gradle file for publishing http://packages.confluent.io/archive/5.1/confluent-5.1.0-2.11.tar.gz
?

Answer (score 2):

Kafka is built with Gradle.

Confluent primarily builds with Maven, and the build scripts are located on private Jenkins servers, with most of the build artifacts uploaded to S3.

The `bin/` package for individual projects is just copied as-is ([which can be done with some Gradle copy task](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/build.gradle)), or sometimes using the `maven-assembly-plugin`, (as [shown here with the Schema Registry](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/package-schema-registry/src/assembly/package.xml))

The `lib/` & `share/java` folders are done similarly, and could be done with a `maven-dependency-plugin`

After each individual repo is done, it mostly is up to shell-scripts to move around the folders and re-package everything.